# Use the image description in question abstract

Tags: feature-request, images

When you insert an image in a question, you're asked to enter an image description :

```
![enter image description here][1]
```

But in question abstract, the image is wholly skipped (at least on chat), even when a description has been entered.

Example with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233258/why-cant-i-bind-directly-console-log-on-ie9-with-developer-tools-open) :

[image]

(the error as text should be visible after "this:")

Wouldn't it be more useful to use the description when it was modified ?